# Magic Number: Checks for magic numbers

Tags: java

I got this warning on Sonar as a violation. I want proper solution to remove this warning from sonar.

My code is like this:

```
void method(){
try {
  int x;
  x=5;
 }
 catch{
    //handling code
 }
}
```

I got warning for this code like:

```
'5' is a magic number.
```

So, I want proper solution to remove such warning.

Comment: declare a `static final int` somewhere with a descriptive name and then use that instead of `5` directly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad

Comment: Instead declare it in a single go. `int x=5;` Or use `@SuppressWarning`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Magic number is the direct usage of the number in the code(i.e., hard-coded number in the code in your case using 5 directly)

to get rid of the warning try this:

```
 int x;
 static final int SOME_NUMBER=5;
 x=SOME_NUMBER;
```

Answer (score 6):

Sonar is asking you to document why you use that particular number by giving it a name. You can do so by declaring a constant (with an expressive name):

```
static final int NUMBER_OF_RETRIES = 5;
```

and then use that constant instead of the "magic" number, thereby expressing the intent of that assignment more clearly:

```
x = NUMBER_OF_RETRIES;
```

This also has the advantage that if NUMBER_OF_RETRIES needs to be changed, you can do so in one place, rather than whereever that "magic" number is used.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm aware that this question has already been answered satisfactorily, but I'd like to add here the own Sonar explanation, since it's quite well elaborated:

> A magic number is a number that comes out of nowhere, and is directly
>   used in a statement. Magic numbers are often used, for instance to
>   limit the number of iterations of a loops, to test the value of a
>   property, etc.
>
> Using magic numbers may seem obvious and straightforward when you're
>   writing a piece of code, but they are much less obvious and
>   straightforward at debugging time.
>
> That is why magic numbers must be demystified by first being assigned
>   to clearly named variables before being used.
>
> -1, 0 and 1 are not considered magic numbers.
>
> **Noncompliant Code Example**
>
> ```
> public static void doSomething() {
>   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){                 // Noncompliant, 4 is a magic number
>       ...
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> **Compliant Solution**
>
> ```
> public static final int NUMBER_OF_CYCLES = 4;
> public static void doSomething() {
>   for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CYCLES ; i++){
>     ...
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> **Exceptions**
>
> This rule ignores hashCode methods.